# How would i go about proving this is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider $C$ the set of circles formed by the two functions $x(\theta), y(\theta)$ which verifies:

$$C =\lbrace \forall r \in \mathbb{R}, \theta \in [0,2\pi]; x(\theta)=r\cos(\theta), y(\theta)=r\sin(\theta) \rbrace $$

Prove that $C$ is a subspace. Any hints or help would be greatly appreciated! thanks.

Comment: You're hoping to prove this set is a subspace...but subspaces are subspaces OF some vector space. Can you tell us what vector space you're considering?

Comment: Say it's $R^2$(I don't know if that makes sense), And we can assume the zero vector is already proven to exist in it...@JohnHughes

Comment: Elements of a subspace are elements of the total space. So your circles must be points in $\Bbb  R ^2$. That doesn't make sense, because they're actually subsets of $\Bbb R^2$. I think you need to decide exactly what question you're asking before you ask us to help you answer it.

Comment: I know it doesn't :D, The moment i read the question i found it weird too, but since i was told i can assume the existence of the zero vector i didn't  question it, i'm just trying to prove $C_1+\lambda C2 \in C$.

Comment: What does $\lambda C_2$ even mean? Multiplication of a set by a scalar isn't generally defined! Perhaps you could type in exactly what the question asks (and even some surrounding context). Why? Well, your set set notation of $C$ also doesn't make sense, so I have the feeling that a good deal may be getting lost in translation.

Comment: What's written before the actual question is: Let $E=\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ the vector space of the functions mapping from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, Only. The question is to 'show' that it's a subspace, I know it sounds weird, the field of the subspace isn't even mentioned, But since this one particular professor is known to be kind of weird with his questions, I just had to assume it's $\mathbb{R}$, and assume that the zero vector already exists in it..

Comment: By the way, $\lambda C_2$ isn't multiplying a set by a scalar, but an element from $C$, I know the notation is weird too, but i guess you can assume my professor means 'Circles with center $O$ and radius $r$'. i know it involves a bunch of assumptions but what can I do right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. First, the space we're looking at is the space of *functions*,
$$
E = \Bbb R^{\Bbb R}
$$
That's got a well-defined addition and scalar multiplication, and a zero vector, namely the function 
$$
z: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto 0.
$$

The set $C$ is a set of functions. I suspect that what's meant is that
$$
C =\lbrace C_r \mid  r \in \mathbb{R} \rbrace
$$
where 
$$
C_r : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2 : \theta \mapsto (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta)
$$
i.e., each $C_r$ is a function, and $C$ is the set of all such functions.

The difficulty here is that $C_r$ is not an element of $E$, because it's a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R^2$ rather than to $\Bbb R$. So assuming that you missed something, I'm going to guess that $E$ is really
$$
E = (\Bbb R^2)^{\Bbb R}.
$$
Once again, addition of functions is defined (via addition of vectors in the codomain) and scalar multiplication arises similarly.

Now the zero function is 
$$
z: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R : x \mapsto (0, 0).
$$

OK. So is $C$ a subspace of this particular (new) vector space $E$? Yes.

For if we take any two elements 
$$
C_r
$$
and 
$$
C_s$
$$
of $C$, 
where $s$ and $r$ are any real numbers, and a number $b$, we can show that 
$$
C_r + b C_s \in C
$$

In fact, it's really quite easy: I claim that 
$$
C_r + b C_s = C_{r + bs}.
$$
We can check that. They are two functions; they have the same domain and same codomain, so all that remains to check is that for every $\theta \in \Bbb R$, we have
$$
(C_r + b C_s)(\theta) = C_{r + bs}(\theta).
$$
Let's do that. 
\begin{align}
(C_r + b C_s)(\theta) 
&= C_r(\theta) + (b C_s)(\theta) & \text{ definition of addition of functions}\\
&= C_r(\theta) + b (C_s(\theta)) & \text{ definition of scalar multiplication of functions}\\
&= (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) + b (s \cos \theta , s \sin \theta) & \text{ definition of $C_u$ for any $u$, given above}\\
&= (r \cos \theta, r \sin \theta) +  (bs \cos \theta , bs \sin \theta) & \text{ definition of scalar multiplication in $\Bbb R^2$}\\
&= ((r+bs) \cos \theta, ((r+bs) \sin \theta)  & \text{ definition of vector addition in $\Bbb R^2$}\\
&= C_{r + bs}(\theta) & \text{definition of $C_u$, for $u = r + bs$}.
\end{align}

And we're done.

Comment: That's how I answered as well, But as you said the whole thing isn't really clear.., But you're definitely right about $E$, but i'm pretty sure he wrote it as $E=R^R$., Oh well, Thanks for your help :)).

Comment: If "that's how I answered, too" is really the case, then I'd suggest rephrasing subsequent questions in the form "Here is what was asked <state question> and here's my answer <write out your answer>. Can anyone confirm that this looks correct, or help me fix it if it's wrong?" That lets us know that you've made some effort; it gives us a hint about what might be a useful response (i.e., at what level you're confused/have misunderstandings); and it lets us see exactly the question we're supposed to be answering --- all kind things to do if you want someone else to volunteer their time for you.

Comment: The question seemed too easy and i kind of know myself to give dumb responses sometimes, so i was kind of reluctant to say what i actually did :D. Thank you for the advice though, will go by it next time.